# In an application that manages its state with Redux,Where it is unsafe to execute code with side-effects, like AJAX calls?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Options are

1. Within Listeners
2. Within function that dispatch Actions
3. Within Reducers
4. Within Middleware

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:
3. Within reducers

The reason is that Redux reducers need to be pure (or deterministic) functions that always return the same result if the same arguments are passed.

So executing code with side-effects inside a reducer would be unsafe, since it would mean the reducer output doesn't only depend on the inputs anymore, but also on the side-effects code.

From the docs:
"reducer functions must always be pure functions"
https://redux.js.org/faq/actions#how-can-i-represent-side-effects-such-as-ajax-calls-why-do-we-need-things-like-action-creators-thunks-and-middleware-to-do-async-behavior